# How to record mic WHILE video calling with Daily.co on iOS Safari

Tags: mobile-safari, audio-streaming, web-mediarecorder, video-conferencing, webrtc-ios

## Problem

With my iPad's iOS Safari, I can use [Daily.co's video API](https://www.daily.co/) to call other devices. But the moment I start recording my local microphone via the [audio-recorder-polyfill library](https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill) , everybody else will no longer be able to hear me, even though I can still hear them and share my camera. Even when the recording session ends, the audio call remains broken (though the audio-recorder works successfully).

It seems iOS specific, because I have no problems with my Surface's Windows Chrome.

## How to reproduce

### Takes around 2 minutes

1. Visit [explain.mit.edu](https://explain.mit.edu) with iPad Safari and any other device. Press the green call button.
2. After confirming the video call works, press the record button on iPad
3. Note the other device can no longer hear anything

## What I tried

First, I guessed the MediaRecorder invalidates the Daily video call's access to the mic, so I used `setLocalDevice` to re-designate access to Daily every 5 seconds to see what would happen. It made no difference during recording, but when the recording ended and it actually did restore the audio call.

So the remaining problem is that the audio call stream just doesn't work mid-recording: I read the MDN docs about the MediaCapture API, it mentioned that a stream has one input and one output, but I don't know what that really means, and whether a mic stream can be simultaneously accessed by two "things".

## Relevant Code

I only use the basic minimum API that Daily and audio-recorder-polyfill provides

Video calling ([full code here](https://github.com/project-feynman/explain-mit/))

```
await this.CallObject.join({
  url: conferenceRoom.url,
  userName: this.sessionID
});
```

Audio recording ([full code here](https://github.com/project-feynman/explain-mit/blob/master/src/components/BlackboardAudioRecorder.vue))

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream); 
this.recorder.start();
```

I don't believe the issue is caused anywhere else, but [here's the full repository code](https://github.com/project-feynman/explain-mit/) if needed

**Real-world context**
For context, I work on https://explain.mit.edu. You go there, request help, then someone else will arrive and use the realtime blackboard and voice chat to explain something to you - and a KhanAcademy-video is made as a by-product. But now if anyone presses "record", the voice chat will stop working.

Comment: Currently trying to clone the MediaStream: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/clone

Comment: Update: it worked. I initialize two independent streams. I pass one to Daily (note you have to unwrap the MediaStream to get the real MediaStream), and the other for recording purposes (for me specifically, each time I start a new recording I also make another copy so each record session is independent, but that's less relevant to this question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can work on a repro case for this, but I have a guess as to what's going on. iOS Safari in the past has stopped any current tracks coming from the local mic/cam any time `getUserMedia()` is called. So, unlike on desktop browsers and Android Chrome, on iOS you can't request or use multiple streams.

iOS Safari is a moving target, and I haven't looked at this specific issue lately. But if that is what's going on, probably you can work around it with a fairly small code change.

Instead of:

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
```

You can grab the local audio track from the Daily call object and make a stream from that:

```
const track = this.callObject.participants().local.tracks.audio.persistentTrack
if (!track) {
  throw new Error("can't start recording right now ... no audio track");
}
this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(new MediaStream([track]));
this.recorder.start();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also received support from your company's live chat (they were the ones to suggest cloning the tracks one to Daily and the other to the recorder...I'll stick with that solution for the time being so I can record videos even if I'm not in a call, but this explanation helped me understand what's actually going on. Overall appreciate the help a ton : )